# Query for parents where all children have a pair/duplicate

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking for direction on a query to get ID's where, for each transaction, return TransDd's where **all** children (could say product,qty,price) have a pair / duplicate value. Example here:

```
TransID      Product   QTY  Price  
1            a         2    1.0
1            a         2    1.0
1            b         3    2.5
2            a         1    1.0
2            a         1    1.0
2            b         2    2.0
2            b         2    2.0
3            a         5    2.0
3            a         4    3.0
4            a         1    2.0
4            a         1    2.0
4            b         2    2.0
4            b         2    2.0
4            c         1    1.0
```

In this example, only transID 2 would be returned.

so far, I'm stuck along the lines of

```
select transid, product, qty, price
     , row_number() over (partition by transid, product, qty, price order by transID desc) rk 
from x
```

But I think I'm on the wrong track there. Appreciate any direction.

Comment: From the above example, only transID 2 would qualify

Comment: The first 2 rows are identical. Why `TransID 1` is not included in your result set?

Comment: What is a parent and what is a child?

Comment: @codedifferent because not all of the children [product qty price] have a duplicate for transID 1. Only the first two rows

Comment: @john transID is considered the parent here, and distinct product,qty,price is a child

Comment: @Scotch . . . Such a nice illustration of why tables should have unique primary keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using `count()` instead of `row_number()`:

```
select transid
from (select x.*,
             count(*) over (partition by transid, product, qty, price) as cnt 
      from x
     ) x
group by transid
having min(cnt) > 1;
```

However, that is sort of overkill, you could also use `group by` in the subquery:

```
select transid
from (select transid, product, qty, price, count(*) as cnt
      from x
      group by transid, product, qty, price
     ) x
group by transid
having min(cnt) > 1;
```

Comment: This would not work if in 6th row you would have `Product=a` and on 5th row `b`. You don't count them independently.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn . . . I don't think we are interpreting the question the same way.  The OP is pretty clearly looking for complete row duplicates, as far as I can tell.  Note the OPs comment:  "@john transID is considered the parent here, and distinct product,qty,price is a child ".

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes - this is what I was looking for - Thanks! I think you are the only one that read the question...or maybe I was unclear. Either way, this is it.

Comment: Don't worry Gordon, I don't think the OP was either. :) My and your queries are effectively the same yet mine is "wrong.". :)

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, this should get you the answer you want:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.SampleData (TransID int, Product char(1), Qty int, Price decimal(2,1));
INSERT INTO dbo.SampleData (TransID,
                            Product,
                            Qty,
                            Price)
VALUES (1,'a',2,1.0),
       (1,'a',2,1.0),
       (1,'a',2,1.0),
       (1,'b',3,2.5),
       (2,'a',1,1.0),
       (2,'a',1,1.0),
       (2,'b',2,2.0),
       (2,'b',2,2.0),
       (3,'a',5,2.0),
       (3,'a',4,3.0);

WITH Counts AS (
    SELECT TransID,Product,Qty,
           COUNT(*) AS Dups
    FROM dbo.SampleData
    GROUP BY TransID, Product, Qty)
SELECT TransID
FROM Counts
GROUP BY TransID
HAVING MIN(Dups) >= 2;

DROP TABLE dbo.SampleData;
```

Comment: This would not work if in 6th row you would have `Product=a` and on 5th row `b`. You don't count them independently.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn is correct: this would include transID 2 which does not have duplicates for every child. This query returns transID's that have duplicates, not transID's that have `all` duplicates

Comment: @Scotch  have you run the above? The example returns 2 and only 2. You state, in your question *"In this example, only transID 2 would be returned."* If 2 is correct, how can it also be wrong??

Comment: @MichałTurczyn Check the CTE again, `GROUP BY TransID, Product, Qty`

Comment: @Scotch for example if the first row was duplicated again (as per the update in the answer). Still just returns 2. Effectively my answer and Gordon's are identical, just his uses a SubQuery (I use a CTE) and he has `>1` (and I use `>=2` which is the same in terms of integers).

Comment: Apologies, @Lamu  -- I was reading it incorrectly. After loading some sample data and looking at it, you are correct!

Answer (score 0):

Use NOT EXISTS and check for IDs where there does not EXIST a row that doesn't have a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

```
select TransID 
from table
except
select TransID
from table 
group by TransID, Product, QTY, Price 
having count(*) = 1
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
select transid,
       product, 
       qty, 
       price
from (
    select transid,
           product, 
           qty, 
           price,
           count(*) over (partition by transid, product) cntproduct,
           count(*) over (partition by transid, qty) cntqty,
           count(*) over (partition by transid, price) cntprice
    from my_table
) a where cntprice > 1 and cntproduct > 1 and cntqty > 1
```

Comment: This is actually returning all rows with duplicates

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT TransID FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count, TransID, Product, QTY, Price
    FROM x
    GROUP BY TransID, Product, QTY, Price
    HAVING Count = 2
) AS Table1
NOT IN
SELECT TransID FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count, TransID, Product, QTY, Price
    FROM x
    GROUP BY TransID, Product, QTY, Price
    HAVING Count = 1
) AS Table2
```

Then read the TransID. Done!